# Google App Engine oauth2 Callback 404

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api, gcloud, google-python-api

with the following code I am getting a 404 resource not found error after clicking authorize button for google drive. My code is below- any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

```html
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets

import webapp2



try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None
except SystemExit:
    flags= None
#
## If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
## at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive API Quickstart'

decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets( CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,SCOPES)

service = build('drive', 'v3')

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    # Get the authorized Http object created by the decorator.
    http = decorator.http()
    # Call the service using the authorized Http object.
    request = service.files().list(q = "mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", pageSize=1000,  )
    response = request.execute(http=http)
    
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

I have https://drive-156701.appspot.com/oauth2callback with and without a / at the end as redirects, which I thought where the correct redirect urls? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a URL handler for `/oauth2callback`.  You only have a url handler for `/`.  Try:

```
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/oauth2callback', Oauth2CallbackHandler),
    ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

and make a `Oauth2CallbackHandler` class to handle the callback.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to including the :

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
        [
            ('/', MainHandler),
            (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler()),
            ],
        debug=True)

The @decorator.oauth_required handles the callbacks for you.

Check out this video:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoUdWBzUZ-M
You need to create credentials for both localhost development and deployed.

And make sure you have checked out:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27
Your api imports must be handled like 3rd party imports, details here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation